# Дружат ли поисковая выдача и heroku

Tags: seo, heroku, развертывание

У Heroku есть на выбор несколько тарифных планов - free, hobby(от 7$), standart(от 25$), perfomance(от 25$). Наслышан что бесплатные хостинги плохо ранжируются поисковыми алгоритмами. Вопрос в следующем, при должной рекламе и хорошем контенте, попадет ли мой сайт в поисковую выдачу если я буду использовать тариф hobby? Хотелось бы услышать ответ от тех у кого есть опыт работы с heroku.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

На бесплатном тарифе далеко не уедете. Хероку будет каждые полчаса бездействия отправлять ваш инстанс в ожидание (считай, сон). И повторное обращение к нему будет с ощутимой задержкой, порядка ~3 сек. Думаю, для SEO это критично.

По поводу платных тарифов - не вижу разницы от обычной аренды виртуального сервера, все то же самое, только уже само деплоит ваши проекты и не требует особых навыков настройки.

Comment: Насчет бесплатного тарифа знаю, поэтому его не рассматриваю. Однако насчет инстанса есть решение, можно делать запросы на сервер каждые 15 минут, он тогда не будет в сон уходить) По поводу платных тарифов спасибо за ответ)